# working with google map and GMSMarker activityIndicator is not presenting

Tags: xcode, google-maps-markers, uiactivityindicatorview

I'm implementing this function presenting a custom info window

```
- (BOOL)mapView:(GMSMapView *)p_mapView didTapMarker:(GMSMarker *)p_marker
```

i wish to present an activityIndicator while the data of the info window is loading, the code:

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
activityIndicator.color = [UIColor redColor];
activityIndicator.frame = (markerPoint.x,markerPoint.y, activityIndicator.frame.size.width, activityIndicator.frame.size.height);
[activityIndicator startAnimating];
[self.view addSubview:activityIndicator];
```

but the activityinfo is not showing, inside the same function i'm constructing and loading the info window and adding it to the current map view

```
[self.view addSubview:markerInfoWindow];
```

while debugging i'm noticing that the info window is showing only after the function finished so I'm guessing that is why my activity info is not showing,

how can i force the ui to render in order for the activity indicator to show?

Answer (score 1):

I think perhaps the delegate method you're looking for is

```
-(UIView *)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView markerInfoWindow:(GMSMarker *)marker
```

Document reference for the Google Map SDK and more Marker customization details in the following links.  This has been updated since you posted your question so there's some new delegate methods worth checking out.

[MapView Marker documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/marker)

[MapView delegate methods](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/protocol_g_m_s_map_view_delegate-p)

Comment: I should follow this up by noting that displaying a UIActivityIndicatorView on a google map marker is not going to work as you wish.  This note from google documentation explains why. "Note: The info window is rendered as an image each time it is displayed on the map. This means that any changes to its properties while it is active will not be immediately visible. The contents of the info window will be refreshed the next time that it is displayed."